# OpenLDAP structure and user maintenance based on different roles

Tags: openldap

I'm planning the structure of OpenLDAP server to integrate it with multiple applications(lets say 10 applications).
In this I have 8 internal applications (Web and Mobile Applications) and 2 others say external services like GitLab.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNqao.png)

Our scenario would be like using all the 10 applications with 1000 users. 
Among 1000 users there will be different roles like admin, managers,developers etc.

All the 1000 users will have permission/access to log into the applications(say cn=application3,cn=application4,cn=application5 as shown in picture).

For cn=application1 and cn=application2 (which are external services like GitLab and includes seperate roles as per in external application), only few users will have permission to access/use.

As per our requirement, we have inserted 1000 users in cn=group1. And in that we have moved few users into cn=application1 and cn=application2 who needs access to those applications.
In future, my organization size will increase and number of applications will also increase. For now we are continuing with the structure as shown in picture. Is this best practice to follow?

Can anyone please guide me on how can I work out with this??   As I am newbie to OpenLDAP please let me know if I mentioned anything wrong.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do it this way. Don't try to mirror your organization in the DIT's organization, and don't use parent-child relationships for semantic purposes. Use an organization of the IT that won't have to change, and use attributes to indicate semantic relationships among entries.

You should already have discovered that some users (yourself for example) need to be in more than one group (for example have admin access to the DIT, be able use all app Li cations, ...).to the DIT. So what you're proposing already won't work.

Define a tree consisting of say Users, Roles, Groups, probably System, ..., and use *attributes* to control which groups the users are in.

Use `organizationalRole` for the roles, `groupOfUniqueNqmes` for the group's.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. According to your words, I have created 3 groups(users, roles,applications) and gave access to particular roles (manager, developer etc.).Here, when dealing with external applications, I gave search base as cn=users,dc=example,dc=com and search filter as (&(objectClass=*)(|(cn=?)(mail=?)(roleOccupant=?))). Also I have given search filter in the combination of ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com. But user is not authenticating with these configurations.  Does I need to change anything? Please suggest me.

Comment: Authentication failures don't have anything to do with your original question or this answer. You didn't supply the correct DN or password.

Comment: Why have you withdrawn the accept from this answer?